# Why are vector instructions faster than having many cores?

Tags: gpu, multicore, simd

Modern high-performance computing uses vector instructions, like the SIMT instructions on NVIDIA GPUs (yes, I know that SIMT isn't quite SIMD, but I don't think the difference affects this question). I'd like to know why it's better to operate on vectors than to just have many more cores.

To be concrete, why is it better for GPUs to operate on 32-word vectors than it would be to have 32 times as many cores? I've made some guesses on my own, but I want to hear from people who actually know what they're talking about.

Here are my guesses:

- If each core has some control hardware and some ALU hardware, then a vector core will share one block of control hardware among 32 ALUs, which increases the proportion of the total transistor budget that is spent on computation.
- If you're doing naturally vectorizable operations anyway, then multiple cores would just introduce synchronization problems that you wouldn't have with vector instructions.
- Different words in a vector are *adjacent* to each other, unlike different cores, so you end up loading and operating on memory in 32-word blocks, which is very nice for the cache.

What is the real answer?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10327490/1410711) answer might be useful and somewhat relevant....

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a matter of synchronization. A single-core operation on a vector completes in a much more deterministic time than several cores (threads) operating on multiple data items. Eventually you'll need a wait to synchronize them and for inherintly-vector operations, SIMD is cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

It's a trade-off between how much silicon you use and how much functionality you get - adding SIMD to a core is a relatively small incremental cost in chip area, for a potential 4x, 8x or 16x throughput improvement on vector operations. Increasing the number of cores by 4x, 8x or 16x translates to a *much* bigger increase in chip area (but has the advantage that code doesn't need to be vectorized).

Answer (score 0):

To add another core CPU designers have to duplicate all parts of the pipeline, plus some additional structures to maintain cache coherence. To double the width of SIMD instructions they only have to double the width of the execution units, while all other stages of the pipeline stay the same.